# How to run all AndroidTests with Gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I use Android Studio 1.1.0 and created a new Android project. AS creates this new project with one ApplicationTest. When I call:

```
$ ./gradlew clean createDebugCoverageReport
```

this ApplicationTest is executed. Now I added a new test:

```
public class ActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity>
```

But this new test isn't executed. Whats going wrong? Both test classes are in the same folder:

```
app\src\androidTest\java\eu.the4thfloor.testapp\
```

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "eu.the4thfloor.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    jacoco {
        version = '0.7.3.201502191951'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the wrong constructor.

AS suggested this one:

```
public ActivityTest(Class<MainActivity> activityClass) {
    super(activityClass);
}
```

But with this constructor the test isn't executed. You have to use this constructor:

```
public ActivityTest() {
    super(MainActivity.class);
}
```

The complete test class looks like this:

```
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

public class ActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    public ActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    public void test2() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's constructor problem.

Answer (score 1):

Give only

```
./gradlew test
```

a try.

Comment: for AndroidTests you have to call $ ./gradlew clean connectedCheck